# Съезжает объект при масштабировании

Tags: css

```
<input type="text"  id="passHeight" name="post_data" value="12" maxlength="2" onclick="this.select();"


    #passHeight {
    position: absolute;  
    width: 4.2%;
    height: 61px;
    margin-left: 649px;
    margin-top: 20.4px;
    background-color: #7F2929;
    border-radius: 2px;
    box-sizing: border-box;


    border: none;
    color:#FFFFFF ;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-family: 'PT Sans Caption', sans-serif;
}
```

Когда я начинаю масштабировать страницу, объект начинает уходить вправо (если увеличиваю) или влево (если уменьшаю), по отношению к остальным обьектам

Comment: Прошу, задайте развернутый вопрос.

Comment: @Duoxx Так более понятно?:)

Comment: А желаемый результат?

Comment: @Duoxx Чтобы оставалось на месте

Comment: Тут такое дело, вместе с масштабированием увеличиваются и все величины которые ты задал, например в случае масштабирования в 125% твои 629 пикселей станут 811 пикселей, так это работает.

Comment: @Duoxx Как это предотвратить?

Comment: Сейчас у вас ничего не съезжает, как стоят стабильные 649px, так и продолжают стоять (с поправкой на изменённый масштаб, конечно)

Comment: Как ни странно, не использовать абсолютные величины при позиционировании, практика очень плохая.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

задай вместо margin-left: 649px; margin-top: 20.4px;
left и top те же величины